# Why does adding another network help in double DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, double-dqn

What is the idea behind double DQN?

The target in double DQN is computed as follows

$$
Y_{t}^{\text {DoubleQ }} \equiv R_{t+1}+\gamma Q\left(S_{t+1}, \underset{a}{\operatorname{argmax}} Q\left(S_{t+1}, a ; \boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}\right) ; \boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}^{\prime}\right),
$$
where

- $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}^{\prime}$ are the weights of the *target network*
- $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}$ are the weights of the online value network
- $\gamma$ is the discount factor

On the other hand, the target in DQN is computed as

$$Y_{t}^{\mathrm{DQN}} \equiv R_{t+1}+\gamma \max _{a} Q\left(S_{t+1}, a ; \boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}^{-}\right),$$
where $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}^{-}$ are the weights of the *target network*.

The target network for evaluating the action is updated using weights of the online network and the value fed to the target value is basically the old q value of the action.

Any ideas on how or why adding another network based on weights from the first network helps? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

As the authors of [this paper](https://cs.brown.edu/people/kasadiat/pdf/deep_mellow.pdf) state it:

> In $Q$-learning, the agent updates the value of executing an action in the current state, using the values of executing actions in a successive state. This procedure often results in an instability because the values change simultaneously on both sides of the update equation.  A target network is a copy of the estimated value function that is held fixed to serve as a stable target for some number of steps.

If I remember it correctly, the main concern is that the network could end up in a positive feedback loop, making sufficient exploration of various action and state combinations less likely to occur, which could be detrimental to the learning task.