# Why do we need target network in deep Q learning?

Tags: deep-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl, deep-neural-networks

I already know deep RL, but to learn it deeply I want to know why do we need 2 networks in deep RL. What does the target network do? I now there is huge mathematics into this, but I want to know deep Q-learning deeply, because I am about to make some changes in the deep Q-learning algorithm (i.e. invent a new one). Can you help me to understand what happens during executing a deep Q-learning algorithm intuitively?

Comment: I think also this question goes into the exact same direction: [Why does adding another network help in double DQN?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22443/why-does-adding-another-network-help-in-double-dqn).

Comment: By the way: Here is a video that also explains it nicely as well: https://youtu.be/xVkPh9E9GfE?t=171
I can only recommend that online lecture series.

Answer (score 7):

In DQN that was presented in the [original paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14236) the update target for the Q-Network is $\left(r_t + \max_aQ(s_{t+1},a;\theta^-) - Q(s_t,a_t; \theta)\right)^2$ were $\theta^-$ is some old version of the parameters that gets updated every $C$ updates, and the Q-Network with these parameters is the target network.

If you didn't use this target network, i.e. if your update target was $\left(r_t + \max_aQ(s_{t+1},a;\theta) - Q(s_t,a_t; \theta)\right)^2$,  then learning would become unstable because the target, $r_t + \max_aQ(s_{t+1},a;\theta)$, and the prediction, $Q(s_t,a_t; \theta)$, are not independent, as they both rely on $\theta$.

A nice analogy I saw once was that it is akin to a dog chasing it's own tail - it will never catch it because the target is non-stationary; this non-stationarity is exactly what the dependence between the target and the prediction cause.

Comment: Given that this is a duplicate but your answer is valuable, I think it would have been better to write the answer under https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6982/2444.